# How to include a module's jar as a dependency in another module in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, liferay-7

I have 2 modules, let's call them A, B.

module A .gradle is

```
dependencies {
    compileInclude group: "Service1", name: "Service1", version: "$rootProject.ext.Service1"
    compileInclude group: "Service2", name: "Service2", version: "$rootProject.ext.Service2"
    compileInclude group: "Service3", name: "Service3", version: "$rootProject.ext.Service3"
}
```

module B .gradle is

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly project(":modules:ModuleA")
}
```

I would like to make use of module A's Service1.Jar  in module B, without having to remake another one in module B.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is about transitive dependency management.

Gradle supports that out of the box when using the [`java-library` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation):

- Anything placed in the `api` configuration is exposed transitively to the *compile* classpath of consumers,
- Anything placed in the `implementation` configuration is only exposed to the *runtime* classpath of consumers.

Now, it is also considered best practice to promote to first level dependencies anything that a module requires for compilation. This prevents dependencies from disappearing if the module that brought it transitively no longer does so.

I have no idea however where the `compileInclude` configuration comes from and how it participates into what the module exposes or not.

And you should no longer use `compile` but instead `implementation` in module B.